# extracting common data of current months and last two monnth sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a  table with more than 20000 rows, In one of column i  have month from jan 2014 to Dec 2014, and in another column i have a loan number. Most of the loan Numbers are reapeting every months,now i need to get only the loan Number which are apperead in all three monthy consecutively. For eg if i am getting data for current months i also wanted get data which are common in two months before the current months. The database that i m using is Access DB. Any adivice will be more than a help, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Loans.LoanID, Sum(IIf([period]=[month],1,0)) AS CM, Sum(IIf([period]=[month]-1,1,0)) AS [m-1], Sum(IIf([period]=[month]-2,1,0)) AS [m-2]
FROM Loans
GROUP BY Loans.LoanID
HAVING (((Sum(IIf([period]=[month],1,0)))>1) AND ((Sum(IIf([period]=[month]-1,1,0)))>1) AND ((Sum(IIf([period]=[month]-2,1,0)))>1));
```

I used month as an integer, and didn't make any adjustment for months 1 and 2 to loop back and look at prior year - you should be able to modify this based on the actual format you are using for the month.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try and keep u posted.. Thanks again

Comment: I have a quick question , what does the period stand for in the query.

Comment: "period" is the field in the table containing the month number.  "Month" is the query parameter - when you run the query, it prompts for an input for "Month", which it then compares to the data field [period].  Then it compares (month-1) to [period] to see if the LoanID was active in the prior month, and the same for (month-2) compared to [period]